# Binding to List<Color> in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm currently creating a control that will render SVG's. As part of the control, colour's can be defined by consumer of the control.

Previously, we had something like;

```
<CustomControl Template="{StaticResource Blah}" PrimaryColour="Red" SecondaryColour="Green" />
```

Now this worked fine and 'Blah' would be rendered as Red and Green. However, a 2 colour approach is obviously incredibly limiting. I'm looking to update our control to behave something like this;

```
<CustomControl Template="{StaticResource Blah}" Colours="Red,Green" />
```

To achieve this I added a DependencyProperty named Colours of type Color[]. But I get the following error when I compile the XAML;

"The TypeConverter for "Color[]" does not support converting from a string."

I understand why that's happening but what I want to know is either;

1. How do I convert my list of string to a list of Color?
2. How do I instantiate a list of Color values in the XAML to pass to the Colours property?

Many Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Color[]` property can only be set to a `Color[]` value unless you define a [type converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/typeconverters-and-xaml) that converts a `string` in the XAML to a `Color[]`.

Otherwise this should work:

```
<local:CustomControl>
    <local:CustomControl.Colours>
        <x:Array Type="Color">
            <Color>Red</Color>
            <Color>Green</Color>
        </x:Array>
    </local:CustomControl.Colours>
</local:CustomControl>
```